# Seeking simple vector layer of all countries in world

Tags: vector, data, global

I'm looking for a vector layer of all countries in the world and (only) their mainland borders, to be used in QGIS 3.10.11. I've searched in a quite few places, including [Eurostat](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/countries#countries20), [MapTiler](https://www.maptiler.com/news/2020/06/vector-tiles-in-qgis-3-14/) and [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/) - which I found via various questions and answers on this site.

In Eurostat and MapTiler, I couldn't find the countries in vector format. On Natural Earth, I couldn't download the countries' data because I received an error message saying:

> The site can't be reached. Check if there is a typo in naciscdn.org.

Is there any way to obtain a vector map of all world countries and their borders for analysis in QGIS?

Comment: Ever heard of OSM?

Comment: type `world` in the coordinate box

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange. For countries try naturalearthdata.com.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yeah I tried natural earth, but for some reason I can't download the files. Is this a problem that occurs more often?

Comment: There seems to be some problem with the Naturalearthdata. It seems that data files are stored into Amazon cloud, but I am getting messages like `<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message> 
 <Key>naturalearth/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip</Key>` There is a bug report already in https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/issues.

Comment: For Natural Earth, on their official site, there is a mention, `× Downloads on this server are broken. In the meantime, files are available to download at AWS.` See url https://gist.github.com/DanielJWood/b71237cc200831acf8e637c05ce2c375#file-natural_earth_s3_links-md and for your particular file https://naturalearth.s3.amazonaws.com/10m_cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip